# Import const with useState hook in other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a new guy in the React JS Club and I'm currently working on a dark mode toggle button for my page. I've already written my component with my useState const which makes this work (I also used Bootstrap Framework):

```
function LightButton(){

    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)

    function dark(){
        setDarkMode(!darkMode)
    }

    return(
        <div className="CheckboxContainer" id="ButtonContainer">
            <div className="form-check form-switch Light-Mode">
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" onClick={dark}></input>
                {darkMode === false && <label className="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Dark mode</label>}
                {darkMode === true && <label className="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault"><p className="Dark-Mode">Dark mode</p></label>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It works but does not come out of the LightButton() function. I want to toggle dark mode in other components of my page, but I don't know how can I call my useState const and my dark() function on their JSX files.

Firstly, I wanted to test this hook in my page's header, so I go to my component's folder and get in my header's JSX. I don't know what to do, so I tried this out of curiosity.

I import the entire function.

`import { LightButton } from "../LightButton/LightButton";`

I copy the hook and paste it on the Header() function (I do have other React components inside my header and CSS class names).

```
function Header(){
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)

    function dark(){
        setDarkMode(!darkMode)
    }

    return(
        <>
        {darkMode===false &&<header className="LightHeader">
            <Logo />
            <Navbar />
        </header>}
        {darkMode===true &&<header className="DarkHeader">
            <LogoDark />
            <Navbar />
        </header>}
        </>
    )
}
```

And I get troubled here. Firstly, I import LightButton and declare my dark() function in my Header JSX, but both of them are never used. Secondly, I don't have any button with an onClick event attribute on my header. I added a button tag with the event to check if the hook works on my header and it does, but I don't want another button in my header. I want my checkbox in the LightButton function to toggle dark mode in all of my other components.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly access state of a component in another component. However, you can create a so called **context**, **provider** and **hook**. I've created a small example of how you could do this.

In a file called **ThemeProvider.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";

// We create a context here
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [darkmode, setDarkmode] = useState(false);

    // The next part makes "provides" the values down in the component tree
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkmode, setDarkmode }}>
            {children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
};

// We expose a so called hook to access darkmode and setDarkmode
export const useTheme = () => useContext(ThemeContext);
```

Then we can wrap our routes and other components in **App.jsx** like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./path/to/file";


export function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            {/* Routing and other things, make sure your header component is somewhere in here */}
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Make sure the Header component is somewhere between the ThemeProvider. This will make it so we can access those values.

And finally in **Header.jsx**:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "./path/to/file";

function Header(){
    // We can access it here
    const {darkmode, setDarkmode} = useTheme();

    return (
        <>
            {darkMode===false &&<header className="LightHeader">
                <Logo />
                <Navbar />
            </header>}
            {darkMode===true &&<header className="DarkHeader">
                <LogoDark />
                <Navbar />
            </header>}
        </>
    );
}
```

For more information regarding passing data deeply please checkout the updated React docs [here](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). The hyperlink has a step-by-step guide for this with way more information.

Comment: Oh, I'll check this out. I've been working with React for less than a month so I'm a newbie in this world. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Hope you like it so far, if there's an issue with the implementation or it throws an errors, let me know!

Comment: Hey! I am now writing what you sent me and I am confused. When you put children inside the params of ThemeProvider and the context provider, do you mean those children are all of my React components?

Comment: Good morning! Sorry for the late reply. Yes, the `{children}` part that you see in the params are your components. So let's say you wrap the `ThemeProvider` around your `<Routes>` component, that same component is the child. In turn the `<Routes>` component also has children. It's necessary to put those children inside the render (or return) else it won't render the children. The type of the children that you see here specifically is `React.ReactNode`. Hope this clarifies it a bit

Comment: Good to hear! Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Hey! I've just done it. Didn't know I had to do this, but now I've learned it. Thank you!